# What's the new way to style a React Native 0.61 Button

Tags: react-native

[This old](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/977) post talked about `titleStyle` and `textStyle` but seems to be no longer based on the Button props:

[image]

How to add a style object to a button? Should this now me a custom view instead with some touch capabilites? I need to achieve:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked out react native `Button` props, there is no way you can add style to it if you not gonna copy the source and make it into your own components, you can find it here `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Button.js`.

I suggest you to use `TouchableOpacity` so you can do anything you want IF it's not necessary to use `Button`. Like this:

```
      <TouchableOpacity
        disabled={disabled || disabledNoLoading}
        style={[styles.buttonView, {
          backgroundColor: disabled || disabledNoLoading ? disabledColor : backgroundColor,
          width: buttonWidth,
          marginTop,
          borderColor
        }]}
        onPress={() => {Alert.alert('Pressed')}}
      >
        {
          disabled ? 
           (<Text>Loading...</Text>) 
           : (<Text style={[styles.buttonText, {color: textColor}]}>{text}</Text>)
        }
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Come to think of it, when I was working with Swift 2, I used a custom `buttonView: View` to achieve something like this so it make sense. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway the post you showed above is from `react-native-elements` library not the one in react-native core, it have it own documentation if you still want to use

Comment: Hi. I've just realised. The image shows their Button props so it's really not possible anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity) in order to customise your Button.